# CA1304 on Boilerplate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization, roslyn, aspnetboilerplate

We have a reasonably large project written in .NET Core 2.2, updated to Abp 4.10.1, that we started through Abp's template.

Recently I added [Roslyn analyzers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers/) to the project, and now we have hundreds of warnings, on every instance of the [L method](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/api-docs/html/Overload_Abp_AbpServiceBase_L.htm).

Example:

```
case AbpLoginResultType.InvalidPassword:
    return new UserFriendlyException(L("LoginFailed"), L("InvalidUserNameOrPassword"));
```

Gives us:

> Warning   CA1304  The behavior of 'AbpServiceBase.L(string)' could vary based on the current user's locale settings. Replace this call in 'AbpLoginResultTypeHelper.CreateExceptionForFailedLoginAttempt(AbpLoginResultType, string, string)' with a call to 'AbpServiceBase.L(string, CultureInfo)'.

As I understand from the documentation, the L method is meant to simplify localization calls and [already considers culture](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Localization#how-the-current-language-is-determined), but adding `CultureInfo` information to every call in order to satisfy the Roslyn analyzers would defeat its purpose.

I wouldn't like to suppress this warning at a project level, and the other options we considered seem very time consuming.

So, would there be an effective way to deal with this?

Comment: Doesn't the analyzer offer a fix?

Comment: Replace this call in 'AbpLoginResultTypeHelper.CreateExceptionForFailedLoginAttempt(AbpLoginResultType, string, string)' with a call to 'AbpServiceBase.L(string, CultureInfo)'.
Undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1304) shows the reasons and motivations behind this rule.

It's up to you to decide it this is important to you or not.